# System environment variables not appearing

Tags: android

I'm trying to use Google's Cloud Vision API and by default, it is trying to locate a json file with authentication information. The guide requires that we set the environment variable "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" to the path of the json file. I have done this, but I noticed that the System.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS") is returning null.

I've confirmed that the value of the variable is correct using echo. I've restarted Windows and Android Studio. I'm still getting a null value for my variable.

I'm running Windows 10, Android Studio 3.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

If System.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS") is returning null, that's a strong signal that the attempt to set environment variable did not succeed.

Another way to check the environment variable is from powershell:

```
> gci env:
```

Don't see GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in the output? Then the attempt to set the environment variable did not take effect.

This video explains how to set an environment variable in Windows.  It's way more hassle than it should be.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEroNNzqlF4

After setting the environment variable, close Visual Studio, your command prompts, etc., and *restart them from the Windows Start Menu*.  That should be sufficient to see the new environment variable.  As a last resort, try restarting the machine.

Comment: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is in the output. I confirmed it using powershell right now, but previously used echo in the command prompt. I've restarted the machine and still no luck

Comment: Are running an android application in an android emulator?

Comment: Yes, I'm running the application in the android emulator

Comment: I see.  Then that variable needs to be set within the android emulator.  I don't think setting it in the Windows environment will have any effect.  I haven't used Android Studio, so I don't know how it's done.  I'll delete my original answer in a day or two because it was so far off the mark.